# Manage almost identical data structures in C

Tags: c, oop, data-structures

With the following (simplified) data definition :

```
#define DIM0 10
#define DIM1 15

typedef struct {
    uint32_t var1:
    ...
    int8_t arrayVar1[DIM0];
 } dataClass0;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t var1:
    ...
    int8_t arrayVar1[DIM1];
 } dataClass1;
```

At one given point I must create an array of these structures and process them.

The processing is exactly the same except for the arrays (different length). Right now it's something like:

```
 dataClass0 *data;
 data = (dataClass0 *) malloc(dimension * sizeof (dataClass0));
 // Processing and filling structure
 data[i].var1 = <value>
 ...
```

Right now I have the same function duplicated for each data classs. Is there a way around duplicating code when using these data structures?

Notes:

- Only pure C, no C++;
- I cannot change the data definition (i.e. cannot use `int8_t *arrayVar1` in the struct).
- When processing I receive the type of data to process (0 for class0, 1 for class1, ...).

Comment: This sounds like one of those occasions where a macro might be the most appropriate solution...

Comment: You need the famous **struct hack!**

Comment: Or a *flexible array*, as it is called since C99.

Comment: are you having 1 array each for dataClass0 and dataClass1 or do you want to fill them both in the same array?

Comment: The arrays contain different data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t var1:
    ...
    int8_t arrayVar[];    /* Declare as flexible array, allowed since C99 */
} dataClass;
```

allocate with  something like that:

```
data1 = malloc(sizeof (dataCLass) + DIM1*sizeof ((dataClass*)NULL)->arrayVar[0]);
data2 = malloc(sizeof (dataCLass) + DIM2*sizeof ((dataClass*)NULL)->arrayVar[0]);
or define
#define ALLOCDATA(dim) malloc(sizeof (dataCLass) + (dim)*sizeof ((dataClass*)NULL)->arrayVar[0]);
```

define

```
#define ELEMENT1(data, i) (dataClass*)(((char*)(data))+(i)*(DIM1+sizeof (dataCLass)))
#define ELEMENT2(data, i) (dataClass*)(((char*)(data))+(i)*(DIM2+sizeof (dataCLass)))
```

or if you parametrize the DIM

```
#define ELEMENT(data, i, dim) (dataClass*)(((char*)(data))+(i)*((dim)+sizeof (dataCLass)))
```

enjoy

```
ELEMENT1(data1, i)->var1 = 1;
ELEMENT1(data1, i)->arrayVar1[9] = 4;


ELEMENT2(data2, i)->arrayVar1[14] = 4;
```

or

```
ELEMENT(data1, i, DIM1)->var1 = 1;
ELEMENT(data1, i, DIM1)->arrayVar1[9] = 4;


ELEMENT(data2, i, DIM2)->arrayVar1[14] = 4;
```

Not perfect, but not too weird a construct to not be usable.

EDIT:
The ELEMENT define should be changed to

```
#define ELEMENT1(data, i) (dataClass*)(((char*)(data))+(i)*(DIM1*sizeof ((dataClass*)NULL)->arrayVar[0]+sizeof (dataCLass)))
#define ELEMENT2(data, i) (dataClass*)(((char*)(data))+(i)*(DIM2*sizeof ((dataClass*)NULL)->arrayVar[0]+sizeof (dataCLass)))

#define ELEMENT(data, i, dim) (dataClass*)(((char*)(data))+(i)*((dim)*sizeof ((dataClass*)NULL)->arrayVar[0]+sizeof (dataCLass)))
```

with this change, your arrayVar field can be of any type and is not limited to elements of size 1.

Comment: In C arrays of length `0` are not allowed. What you are reffering two is an extension. The official way of doing what you want is to use `[]` instead of `[0]` and it is called flexible array member.

Comment: sure this changes, just the difference between correct and incorrect code.

Comment: I just read Jens Gustedt's blog entry about flexible arrays and can only recommend people to read it. http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/flexible-array-member/#more-994 . It explains why the allocation formula I used in my response might allocate more data than necessary.

Comment: So basically you mean substitute `[0]` for `[]` and it should be fine? I will give this solution a try and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just make the array dynamic? So that you create your structures with `malloc()` and then initialize some member to hold the size (and make sure it ends with an `uint8_t *` instead of an actual array, or use VLA's)?

Comment: apparently not. `(i.e. cannot use int8_t *arrayVar1 in the struct).`

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether or not you want to fill the arrays with different values initially. Otherwise you can just have a macro that initializes both types of structures

```
#define STRUCTURE_INITIALIZER(VAR1, VAR2) { .var1 = (VAR1), .var2 = (VAR2) }
```

and use that as

```
dataClass0 data = STRUCTURE_INITIALIZER(31, 42);
```

your array components would then always be `0` initialized, regardless of their size.

To initialize an `malloc`ed array of your stuff:

```
dataClass0 *data  = malloc(dimension * sizeof (dataClass0));

// Processing and filling structure
for (size_t i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
  data[i]= (dataClass0)STRUCTURE_INITIALIZER(43, i);
```

BTW, prefer to initialize variables properly and don't cast the return of `malloc`.